# MySQL return TRUE if exists and doesn't match another table

Tags: mysql

I'm making an app to review movies, and I have these tables.

```
mysql> SELECT title, rating, review, username FROM movies;                                                                                         
+------------+--------+--------------+----------+
| title      | rating | review       | username |
+------------+--------+--------------+----------+
| The Matrix |      5 | Great movie! | Ryan     |
| Avatar     |      5 | Cool         | Ryan     |
+------------+--------+--------------+----------+

mysql> SELECT username FROM users;
+----------+
| username |
+----------+
| Ryan     |
| John     |
+----------+
```

What I'm trying to do is return TRUE if the username exists (to show a profile, and if no result show a 404), but doesn't have any reviews associated with it, and return the review data if it exists.

I've tried using `EXISTS(SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = "John")`, and this returns 1 but I can't seem to figure out how to set up an if statement using this.

EDIT: To clarify, I'm trying to return TRUE if the user exists, but hasn't rated any movies, but return the reviews otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

What you want to use is a [JOIN statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).  You want to be able to get information from two tables at the same time in a single result.

For your specific case, you would want to join the `movies` table with the `users` table.  Because you might have records in the `movies` table where the `username` does not exist, you will want to use a `LEFT JOIN`.  Here is a quick snippet to get you started:

```
SELECT 
  m.title, 
  m.rating, 
  m.review, 
  m.username, 
  CASE WHEN u.username IS NULL THEN FALSE ELSE TRUE END as user_exists
FROM movies m 
  LEFT JOIN users u ON u.username = m.username
```

[Here is a SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/79928d/2) to play with as an explanation.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with `SELECT` in front of `EXISTS` since the `IF` conditional isn't really returning a `THEN` it's a little more overhead.

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = 'John') as truth;
```

This will return a column named `truth`.  It will be set to `1` or `0` --

```
1 = true
0 = false
```

Answer (score 2):

**Query**

```
SELECT IF(  EXISTS(SELECT * FROM users  WHERE LOWER(username) ='name' ),'true','false' )AS result
```

Spring data maps String `'true'` or `'false'` to boolean

Answer (score 1):

`1` and `TRUE` are both [**'truthy'**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/truthy).

As such, all you need to do is add an `IF` in front of your existing code:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = "John")
```